# Is there an inverse function of $f(x) = x^2 + \pi\cos x$?

Tags: inverse-function

Is there an inverse function of   $f(x) = x^2 + \pi\cos x$?

I don't think there is because of the $x^2$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: There's none since this is an even function.

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes? There's clearly an attempt to find a solution to the problem!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Note that as the question is posed the correct annswer should be “not sufficient information” or “it depends upon the domain” indeed $f:R\to R$ is not invertible but $f:[\pi/2,+\infty)\to[\pi^4/4,+\infty)$ is bijective and invertible.

Comment: @Plzhelpme Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

$$f (-x)=(-x )^2-\pi\cos (-x)= f (x)$$

$f $ is not injective and therefore it is not bijective.

So it does not have an inverse function.

Comment: Thnks for editing. tnks a lot .

Answer (score 2):

It should be declared over which interval we are considering the function.

Indeed f(x) is not invertible as function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ but it is invertible, for example, if we assume a restriction $[a,+\infty)\to[b, +\infty)$ indeed

- $f’(x)=2x-\pi\sin x>0$ for some $x\ge a$ and $f(a)=b$

and thus $f:[a,+\infty)\to[b, +\infty)$ is bijective.

Comment: In fact $f'(x) > 0$ for $x >  \pi/2$, so it's invertible from $[\pi/2, \infty)$ to $[\pi^2/4, \infty)$.

Comment: @RibertIsrael Yes exactly since $\sin x<x$.